# Dynamic validation FormArray of FormGroup in mat-table not works

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-validation, angular-formbuilder

I have FormGroup in FormArray. Form creates empty, and user filling it. User can edit fields right in a mat-table, but validations is not working if user enter wrong value (validations works only once, in a moment of pushing row).
I did an example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v4g8ep?file=src/app/app.component.ts)
How can i do dynamically validate all form, and the fields in each row, with output labels something like "wrong value" under the field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `[(ngModel)]`, that's good for template driven forms, with validation rules in the template itself. If you want a model-driven form, you must tie the template to the form and form controls, sth more or less like that:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="myForm.controls.tableFields.value" [formGroup]="myForm">
<!-- ... -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="product_count" [formGroupName]="'tableFields'">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Count</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
        <input [formControlName]="'product_count'" />
```

Comment: mbojko, your variant is working, thank you! But, why loosing a focus and cursor after every input char ? [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kg1msk?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: @MichaelSun the table needs a tracking function, otherwise it'll rerender on every input. Putting `[trackBy]="trackByIndex"` on the table element, and defining `trackByIndex = (i) => i;` should do the trick.

Comment: i don't understand where insert `trackByIndex = (i) => i;` but i've create method `trackByIndex(i) { return i; }` in my .ts and - it's working! Thank you, mbojko! [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wrdvdn?file=src/app/app.component.ts)